# Python port scanner not working as it is supposed to

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, port

I tried making a ssh port scanner in python that takes every ip of a class (for example 13.120.x.y). I got no error so far but it takes so long and so far no ip address has the port open (I've been running it for 5 minutes).

EDIT: It seems I do get the message when the port is open.

```
import socket
from datetime import datetime
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

def make_ips(ip_class):
    ip_addresses = [f"{ip_class}.{part3}.{part4}" for part3 in range(0, 256) for part4 in range(0, 256)]
    return ip_addresses


def scan(remoteServerIP):
    print("-" * 60)
    print("Please wait, scanning remote host", remoteServerIP)
    print("-" * 60)
    try:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        result = sock.connect_ex((remoteServerIP, 22))
        if result == 0:
            print(f"{remoteServerIP}: Open")
            return remoteServerIP
        sock.close()
    except socket.gaierror:
        print(f'Hostname {remoteServerIP} could not be resolved.')
    except socket.error:
        print(f"Couldn't connect to server {remoteServerIP}")


def main():
    t1 = datetime.now()
    ipclass = str(input("please input the ip class: "))
    ips = make_ips(ipclass)
    hostnames = []
    pool = ThreadPool(13)
    hostnames = pool.map(scan, ips)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    open("hosts.txt", "w").write(hostnames).splitlines()
    t2 = datetime.now()
    total =  t2 - t1
    print('Scanning Completed in: ', total)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: How are you giving the input? Can you give an example?

Comment: @AbhishekRai what you are getting from make_ips is a list of ip addresses that use the same ip class. For example: if the ip class is 15.30 then the ip addresses generated will be from 15.30.0.0 to 15.30.255.255.

Comment: No ..what are you giving as input? what values?

Comment: @AbhishekRai as i said if i want to scan all ip addresses from 15.30.0.0 to 15.30.255.255 then the input will be 15.30

Comment: @AbhishekRai no, i am only interesed in ssh port (22)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I had to use more threads.

```
import socket
from datetime import datetime
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

def make_ips(ip_class):
    ip_addresses = [f"{ip_class}.{part3}.{part4}" for part3 in range(0, 256) for part4 in range(0, 256)]
    return ip_addresses


def scan(remoteServerIP):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    result = sock.connect_ex((remoteServerIP, 22))
    if result == 0:
        print(f"{remoteServerIP}: Open")
        return remoteServerIP
    sock.close()


def main():
    ipclass = str(input("please input the ip class: "))
    ips = make_ips(ipclass)
    pool = ThreadPool(20000)
    hostnames = pool.map(scan, ips)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    for hostname in hostnames:
        if hostname:
            open("hosts.txt", "a").write(f"{hostname}\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```